# AWS Lambda NET 6: how to deploy it from Github to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What I need to do:

1. I have Github account, create a repository for my Lambda NET 6 project and upload it to the repository. Ok, should this repository be private or public? Should it have any special permissions?
2. How and where in AWS to add reference to this project? how to build it and deploy?
3. How and where can I add AWS Gateway settings in this deployment?
4. Can end user use it after deployment?